# System.Data.EvaluateException HResult=0x80131920 Message=Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Int32 and System.String

Tags: c#

```
public void MatchedDocumentsInFileCabinet(string MainFolder, string SubFolder, string FileName, string FilePath)
{
    // Checking Main Folder is present in FileCabinet, if present retrieving MainFolderID if not Inserting MainFolderName

    if (SelectedFileCabinetID == "")
    {
        SelectedFileCabinetID = "1";
    }
    int Mainfoldercount = 0;

    DocSortResult getfolderdetails = objFolderManager.GetFolderDetails();
    DataTable getFolderNames = new DataTable();
    if (getfolderdetails.resultDS != null && getfolderdetails.resultDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        // Following line is showing error
        DataRow[] drResult = getfolderdetails.resultDS.Tables[0].Select("FileCabinet_ID = '" + SelectedFileCabinetID + "'" + "and" + " ParentFolderID = '" + "0" + "'" + "and" + " IsDelete = '" + "True" + "'");
        if (drResult.Count() != 0)
        {
            getFolderNames = drResult.CopyToDataTable();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately it's hard to understand your question as it consists only of code - and a lot of code, at that. Please reduce this to a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem, and add a description of the problem in the body of the question. Hopefully we'll then be able to help you.

Comment: A good quality question should avoid walls of code, describe what you are trying to accomplish and the spected and actual behavior. I would advice checking the help section, that has [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This kind of questions could be solved by debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing `getfolderdetails.resultDS.Tables[0]` structure is hard to know which column is, but one of those columns is integer and your `Select(filter)` is telling that all the fields are string.

An example of your code debugging would show `.Select("FileCabinet_ID = '4' and  ParentFolderID = '0' and IsDelete = 'True' ")`. And the error message says one of them is not a string.

I would bet that `IsDelete = 'True'` probably will be boolean (bit column in SQL Server) and `FileCabinet_ID` or `ParentFolderID` or both of them are integer (and this is causing the error).

Set a breakpoint and check the datatypes of the datacolumns you are trying to filter.